# How to tell if an APC is executed?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, memory

An asynchronous procedure call (APC) is a procedure that executes asynchronously in the context of a particular thread. Windows provide us `QueueUserAPC` to install an APC on a thread. 
I'm writing a program which injects a dll into a target process using `APC`.

Here's the steps:

1. `OpenProcess()`
2. `VirtualAllocEx()` to alloc space for dll name
3. Copy the dll's name to allocated address using `WriteProcessMemory()`
4. Insert APC to execute `LoadLibrary()`

It's all perfect but how do we know if the APC installed is executed? I need to release the memory allocated in step 2.

Comment: The obvious way, let it produce an observable side effect.  Like signaling a named event with SetEvent().  Although "never" ought to be an expected outcome, the thread has to co-operate by using an alertable wait.  Not the kind of thing you can ever really hope for in arbitrary code that you don't control.